# Center aligning list of images

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc

[image]
Can some CSS guru help me getting this layout.

What I have here is

```
<div class="movieList">  
<div class="image" selected = true>  
 <img class="poster" src="image1" selected = true/>  
</div> 
 <div class="image">   
<img class="poster" src="image1"/>  
</div>  
<div class="image"> 
  <img class="poster" src="image2"/>
 </div> 
 .
 .

</div>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

Start with:

```
.cover {
  float:left;
  margin-left:-50px;
}
```

and go from there.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/steve/T2qHR/ (centered, pure CSS, enlarging effect)

Comment: thks for the quick anwser I got the basic layout how would center align those images...please write in detail.thks

Comment: @Eric..please read my above comment..and what u did is much appreciated. I want to center align images and image right side part should be shown.

Comment: thks for second update.please try put actual images and right half should only be visible and on hover images should look like above and next image should be visible.

Answer (score 1):

See this http://www.jsfiddle.net/hKQcX/4/

```
$(function(){

    $('.movie').live('mouseover', function(){

    var $movie = $('.movie'); 
    $movie.css('z-index', 0);
    $movie.css('opacity', .50);
    $movie.css('width', '100px');
    $movie.css('height', '150px');
    $movie.css('margin-top', '0');

    var $this = $(this);
    $this.css('z-index', 100);
    $this.css('opacity', 1.00);
    $this.css('width', '120px');
    $this.css('height', '180px');
    $this.css('margin-top', '-15px');

    });

    var i=0;
    for (i;i<10;i++){
    if(i%2==0)
      $('#container').append('<div class=\"movie red \"></div>');
    else
      $('#container').append('<div class=\"movie green\"></div>')
     }
});
```

in your css

```
#container{
  margin-left: 50px;
  margin-top: 100px;
}

.movie{
  position: relative;
  float:left;
  width:100px;
  height: 150px;
  margin-left:-50px;
}

.red{
  background-color:red;
  opacity: .5;
}

.green{
  background-color:green;
  opacity: .5;
}
```

Comment: Thks for the detailed explaination...please try put actual images and right half should only be visible and on hover images should look like above and next image should be visible. I think this can be achieved with CSS no jquery required.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display them than Steve has the right answer, if you want to align that container in the center then:

```
.cover {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width:600px;
}
```